# jquerymobile button link doesn't work, works if i refresh the page

Tags: jquery, mobile, button, hyperlink, anchor

here's the button that links to the second page

```
<a href="#game" id="play-button" data-role="button">Play!</a>
```

and this links to

```
    <!-- Game page -->
        <div id="game" data-role="page" data-content-theme="a">
        ... page content
```

this "Play" button doesn't work unless I refresh the page. What could be the cause of that?
I tried changing the link to "gamepage.html#game", tried adding data-ajax="false" but it didn't fix it.

Comment: are these on the same page?

Comment: It's on the same html file, if this is what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to link the same page, with different hash, as i know, in  jQuery Mobile beta 3, they fix this issue, but for older version, you need to enable self-links.